# Reputation points and badges not incremented

Tags: support, status-bydesign, editing, reputation, badges

My reputation points and badges suddenly stopped increasing on Ask Ubuntu...

I have done some reviews today and I was also supposed to be awarded a gold badge for editing 500 posts. This started today. Everything was fine yesterday...

How do I get all the reputation points I should have had today and my badge too?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get only 1000 rep from edits, so, 500 edits = 1000 rep, you cannot earn anymore via editing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) on both the badge and reputation counts.

---

***The Badge***

Keep in mind that the [requirements for the Copy Editor Badge](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) are as follows (bold emphasis mine):

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or **deleted posts** and tag edits)

If you look at your [reputation tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/531149/yufenyuy-veyeh-dider?tab=reputation) you'll note that there are a number of deleted posts that correspond to the edits you made.  Since those posts are deleted now, they don't count to your badge (and the rep +2s you did get from the edits there are gone because of the deletion).

This applies perpetually, so you need to edit *more* in order to get the badge, and not have the posts be deleted.  There is also a lag time between getting the "post amount" and the badge actually being awarded due to automatic processes, so keep that in mind as well.

Note that once you do earn the Copy Editor badge it stays, so you won't lose it once you do earn it.

You might want to read more on [Meta.SE about how badges work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work/17854#17854).

---

***The Reputation***

**There is a reputation gain limit for edits.**  The cap for gaining reputation with *edits alone* is 1000.  Judging by the huge number of edits you've been doing, and your claims that you aren't getting your 500 edits badge, you've likely hit this cap, **and thus will no longer receive reputation just from edits** (500 edits times 2 rep per edit equals 1000 reputation from edits, i.e. the rep cap).

So, if you want more reputation, you now need to contribute **beyond** just doing edits.

There's two additional points to keep in mind as well, though they only apply of the rep cap hadn't been reached:

1. If you have pending edits that haven't been accepted, you won't get rep until those are approved, provided that you haven't hit a rep cap for edits already.
2. If you check your rep tab, you'll note that when posts got deleted you *lost* the edit rep points.  Which means you're actually -8 reputation from yesterday currently.

Comment: Two minor points - the rep cap apparently doesn't count rep gained from deleted posts (we can tell from the present case because when they stopped gaining rep for edits, OP had 593 approved edits total) so if you lose rep for posts you edit being deleted, you can get it back by editing again, in theory. See bottom of https://askubuntu.com/reputation? Second, just in case it's not clear to others from your answer, once you have a badge, it stays, even if you only met the criteria briefly. So if you make 500 qualifying edits, you'll get and keep the badge, even if the posts are later deleted.

Comment: @Zanna "... once you have a badge, it stays, ...", except tag badges, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Zanna the reference to 'you keep it' was specific to this one badge.  (If you wish to nitpick, just edit the answer yourself as I am not that picky about that happening - if the edits are too substantial or problematic I'll revert them)

Comment: @pomsky unsurprisingly you are absolutely correct. I bothered to look it up (thanks for prompting me to do what I should have done anyway :)) and found [this very useful MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/322419) on badges.