# Will I still get +2 for editing questions and answers after I reach 2000 reputation?

Tags: support, editing, reputation

I have been active on Ubuntu for one year...
I am about to achieve 2000 reputation.

At the moment, with reputation 1658, all my edits are peer reviewed and once they are accepted, I am getting a reputation +2.

What will happen once I reach 2000 and edit posts; will those +2 points still come or nothing?

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18268/reputation-points-and-badges-not-incremented/18269#18269

Comment: ya had a look..nice.. thank you.

Comment: The way I think about it is, you can only get reputation on Stack Exchange for peer-reviewed actions. When you can edit as much as you like, that no longer applies. BTW thanks for your many contributions to the site, not just editing & posting but leaving comments that help people improve their posts and [finding dupes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3877?m=47168174#47168174), voting and flagging etc. Not all useful actions give reputation, but they are much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually get +2 reputation points from *suggested* edits, and not from edits. And once you hit 2k, you will not be able to suggest edits but you will be doing direct edits.

Simply put, once you hit 2k, you won't get +2 rep from editing posts.

However, you would still get +2 reputation if you suggest edits on tag wikis until you reach 20k reputation and get the [Trusted User](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege. As until then, you cannot edit tag wikis directly, you would still be submitting *edit suggestions*.

Comment: can you share some links.. i am not clear about tag wikis

Comment: I never found an official post (whether a question, answer or help article) that mention the reputation from tag wikis. But you can check [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368234/535122) and [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15465/8698). The latter one is mine, but if you check the edit history, you can see that a mod had corrected it. You can also check the following privilege which discusses tag wikis https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user.

Comment: Thank You.. your answer and comments were very helpful.

Comment: FYI, edit rep stops after a certain *number* of accepted edits - 500 of them to be exact (a 1000 rep gain cap), not necessarily rep itself.  See my answer to another question [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18268/reputation-points-and-badges-not-incremented/18269#18269).  It also stops if you hit 2000 rep and get edit privs, whichever happens first.

Comment: For PRATAP and as a reference to what Thomas shared, check [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/333472)